# How to access authenticated URL in Android?

Tags: android

I want to parse the data from RSS Feed that is password protected. If I try to parse the data, it's throwing "File not found Exception"

Here is my code:

```
try {
                DBF = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DB = DBF.newDocumentBuilder();
                url_val = new URL("http://admin:admin@dev.quaddeals.com/university-of-illinois/androids/city.rss");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                try {
                    dom = DB.parse(url_val.openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                elt = dom.getDocumentElement();
                NodeList items = elt.getElementsByTagName("item");
                for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node item = items.item(i);
                    NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
                    for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node property = properties.item(j);
                        String name = property.getNodeName();

                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                            cityTitle = property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();                                
                        }
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {

                            cityId = property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        }
                    }
                    title.add(cityTitle);
                    id.add(cityId);
                }
                   VALUE1 = new String[title.size()];
                    Iterator<String> itc = title.iterator();
                    while (itc.hasNext()) {
                        l1++;
                        VALUE1[l1] = itc.next().toString();                 
                    }

                    VALUE2 = new String[id.size()];
                    Iterator<String> it1c = id.iterator();
                    while (it1c.hasNext()) {
                        m1++;
                        VALUE2[m1] = it1c.next().toString();
                    }

        } catch (Exception e) {



        }
```

My Log Cat shows error as follows:

```
02-21 23:20:48.893: WARN/System.err(19206): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://dev.quaddeals.com/university-of-illinois/androids/city.rss

02-21 23:20:48.893: WARN/System.err(19206):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1064)

02-21 23:20:48.893: WARN/System.err(19206):     at com.fsp.quaddeals.DealCities$SelectDataTask_Deals.doInBackground(DealCities.java:341)

02-21 23:20:48.893: WARN/System.err(19206):     at com.fsp.quaddeals.DealCities$SelectDataTask_Deals.doInBackground(DealCities.java:1)
```

If I enter [this URL](http://admin:admin@dev.quaddeals.com/university-of-illinois/androids/city.rss) in browser it will ask for the authentication, after that it will redirected to the original RSS FEED where my parsing data exists.

I want to parse the data in the this page. How can I access this password protected page and parse the data? Whether Android supports SSL connections.

Comment: You also miss to call openConnection.connect() before getInputStream()

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here.  You can set it manually, like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://admin:admin@dev.quaddeals.com/university-of-illinois/androids/city.rss");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

if (url.getUserInfo() != null) {
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(url.getUserInfo().getBytes()));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
}

dom = DB.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

You can use `java.net.Authenticator`, but it works globally (on all URLs):

```
// see https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Authenticator.html
// and https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/PasswordAuthentication.html
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("admin", "admin".toCharArray());
    }
});
```

You can use a library like [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley) ([example](https://gist.github.com/jchernandez/5bec1913af80e2923da8)), or my personal preference, [okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) ([example](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/11/03/basic-authentication-okhttp-example/)).